# Error log record number: 813600142036

Tags: magento2, log, error-log

I am trying to login and I'm getting Error log record number: 813600142036
Does anyone know what this means?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Go to the path magento2root/var/report/813600142036  and check the file

Comment: And edit and update your question (and title) here with the details. Also mention where you get this error (what page) and what you did before that.

Comment: Go to App  folder and open your bootstrap.php file and enable Error reporting (ini_set('display_errors', 1))  and then update your question with error code.

Answer (score 3):

Go to magento/var/report and open the file with the Error log record number name i.e 673618173351 in your case. In that file you can find the complete description of the error.

For log files like system.log and exception.log, go to magento/var/log/.
Possible causes are :-
1- Your Data base details are not correct in local.xml file. 
2- Domain name which you have mentioned in back-end is different.